# How does dark matter distribution help to identify it's composition

Tags: gravity, cosmology, radiation, dark-matter, galaxies

A question regarding this recently released data,

[image: Dark Matter Distribution]

and the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.01538 that details it's distribution:

Abstract:

> We use 26 million galaxies from the Dark Energy Survey (DES) Year 1 shape catalogs over ≥1321 deg$^2$ of the sky to produce the most significant measurement of cosmic shear in a galaxy survey to date. We constrain cosmological parameters in both the flat $\Lambda CDM$ and $w CDM$ models, while also varying the neutrino mass density. These results are shown to be robust using two independent shape catalogs, two independent photo-$z$ calibration methods, and two independent analysis pipelines in a blind analysis. We find a 3% fractional uncertainty on $\sigma _8(\omega_m/0.3)^{0.5}=0.789 (+0.024−0.026)$ at 68% CL, which is a factor of three improvement over the fractional constraining power of our DES Science Verification results and a factor 1.5 tighter than the previous state-of-the-art cosmic shear results. In $w CDM$, we find a 5% fractional uncertainty on $\sigma_8(\omega_m/0.3)^{0.5}=0.789 (+0.036−0.038)$ and a dark energy equation-of-state $ =−0.82 (+0.26−0.48)$. Though we find results that are consistent with previous cosmic shear constraints in $\sigma_8 - \omega_m$, we nevertheless see no evidence for disagreement of our weak lensing data with data from the CMB. Finally, we find no evidence preferring a $w CDM$ model allowing $w ≠−1$. We expect further significant improvements with subsequent years of DES data, which will more than triple the sky coverage of our shape catalogs and double the effective integrated exposure time per galaxy.

The write ups  in the popular science media: [Dark Matter Distribution](http://www.bbc.com/news/health-40817897), as one example, claims that this distribution map may help identify (or at least eliminate some of), the contenders for dark matter constituents. This summary below is obviously clear enough for lay people, but of the abstract, I honestly follow only about 10 percent currently.

> Researchers have released the most accurate map ever produced of the dark matter in our Universe.
>   The team surveyed more than 26 million galaxies in the largest study of its kind.
>   The map will help scientists understand what dark matter is made from and learn more about another mysterious phenomenon called dark energy.
>   The results have been released by the international Dark Energy Consortium (DES).
>   According to Professor Ofer Lahav of University College London (UCL), and chair of the DES Advisory Board, the map would provide new insights into how the Universe operates.
>   "Dark energy and dark matter represent probably one of the biggest mysteries in the world of science. And this has generated a lot of interest across the whole of science."

My question: I wonder if it is possible, without turning this into a list question,  to give more details on how the two aspects, distribution and composition, are linked?

Before posting this question, I read through [Dark Matter: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter), but a simple  summary would help a newbie.  I would appreciate a short overview, in semi-basic terms, of how the new data would help determine the DM composition.

My naive  (and incorrect) view after reading the Wikipedia article, was: how does this help, if gravity is gravity, irrespective of its source? In light of the claim in my title, this is obviously too simplistic, (or the claim is hyped, which I don't believe), so then my thought was, ok it must be radiation that gives more detail,  but this implies interactions that DM, by definition, should not be involved in, at least directly.

A comment by Rob Jeffries below reminded me (embarrassingly, as I should have known) that this is  a question based on the distribution  and interaction of matter (of both kinds) from the early epoch of the universe, but very careful reading of the paper  is something I need to do, as illustrated by my uninformed musings above.

Obviously, I have underestimated the importance of the clues available, but I wonder how the distribution map helps.

A brief pointer in the right direction would allow me to read the Wikipedia article (and possibly even the paper cited above), with a better understanding.

Apologies for the erronous mathjax in the abstract, I will edit it again shortly.

Comment: How warm or cold the dark matter is (i.e. what mass are the constituents) will certainly affect how it clumps as a function of cosmic epoch.

Comment: @safesphere yes, I do appreciate the difference, and i appreciate your comment in letting me know, but it is about dark matter, confusingly as part of a  dark energy survey. Once the 40 plus (I think) authors publish in the usual way, hopefully soon, they will clarify as to how the by product of a dark energy survey leads to dark matter distribution and thus my question. But it is  about dark matter, (although I admit it's  not impossible that a few pop sci sources got mixed up ) thanks and regards.